# English - French dictionary(Maths)

Tags: reference-request, translation-request, mathematical-french

I would like to have an English - French dictionary for higher math ( Master, Doctorate ) . Can you suggest me some ( available online) ?  Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Here: http://www.math.umn.edu/~kwlan/documents/french-glossary.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402104/mathematics-in-french?rq=1